# How to get Order numbers where collection number has a top and a corresponding bottom?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is how the main order table looks :-

```
|  Order_num   | Collection_Num |
+--------------+----------------+
|  20143045585 |   123456       |
|  20143045585 |   789012       |
|  20143045585 |   456897       |
|  20143758257 |   546465       |
+--------------+----------------+
```

These are the collections:-

```
|    tops      |      bottom    |
+--------------+----------------+
|  353735      |   745758       |
|  123456      |   789012       |
|  456456      |   456897       |
|  323456      |   546465       |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Desired Output:-

```
|  Order_num   |
+--------------+
|  20143045585 |
```

Here Order number 20143045585 has both a top and a bottom from the same row in table number 2 (each row in 2nd table forms a particular combination called 'A Collection' i.e. 1 top and corresponding bottom ).
What I want to know -
All the order numbers which have a top and a corresponding bottom in 'Collection_num' column.
Can anyone help me with a SQL code for this ?

Let me know if any of this is unclear.

Comment: provide sample output?

Comment: You need some way to identify your collection data. You need a unique value in those rows. As it sits you have no way of knowing if 353735 and 745758 are the same row without a lot of unnecessary gyrations.

Comment: Sample output - 
 |   Order_Num  |
 |20143045585  |

Since that order has a top and a bottom paid from same collection

Comment: @SeanLange I can add an index to 2nd table, identifying each collection. (that data is still in excel and hence I have that flexibility.)
Will that help ?

Comment: By Index I think you mean a new column for something like CollectionID or something? Also, you should add the desired output to the question instead of a comment.

Comment: Yes. A new column like CollectionID (1,2,3..) just numbering the rows to make it easier to reference a pair of a top and a bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Order_num
From table_1 as A
where exists
(select tops from table_2 as B where B.tops = A.Collection_num) 
AND
(select bottom from table2 as B where B.bottom = A.Collection_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you just have the first table of data and each order can only have the two relevant collections or less.  Perhaps:

```
select T1.Order_Num
      ,T1.Collection_Num AS Tops
      ,T2.Collection_Num AS Bottom
from Table1 T1
inner join Table1 T2
   on T1.Order_Num = T2.Order_Num
   and T1.Collection_Num < T2.Collection_Num
order by T1.Order_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using subquery

```
select distinct order_num from #yourorder where collection_num 
    in (select tops from #yourcollections) 
    and order_num in
    ( select order_num from #yourorder where collection_num in
         (select bottom from #yourcollections) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that something like this should work for you. I am just using the ctes here to create the test data so it can be queried.

```
with Orders (OrderNum, CollectionNum) as
(
    select 20143045585, 123456 union all
    select 20143045585, 789012 union all
    select 20143045585, 456897 union all
    select 20143758257, 546465 
)
, Collections (CollectionID, tops, bottoms) as
(
    select 1, 353735, 745758 union all
    select 2, 123456, 789012 union all
    select 3, 456456, 456897 union all
    select 4, 323456, 546465
)

select o.OrderNum
    , t.tops
    , b.bottoms
from Orders o
join Collections t on t.tops = o.CollectionNum
join
(
    select o.OrderNum
        , b.bottoms
        , b.CollectionID
    from Orders o
    join Collections b on b.bottoms = o.CollectionNum
) b on b.CollectionID = t.CollectionID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that I used:

```
Select * 
From  (select A.Order_num, B.Coll_ID, B.Bottoms from Orders_table as A
        Join Collections_Table as B
         on A.Collection_num = B.Bottoms
       ) as C 
  join
      (select K.Order_num, M.Coll_ID, M.Tops from Orders_table as K
        Join Collections_Table as M
         on A.Collection_num = B.Tops
       ) as D 
  on C.Orders_B = D.Orders_Num AND C.Coll_ID = D.Coll_ID
)
```